# cursor gone in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt4, onfocus

I have a window containing multiple `QRowWidget`s, which are custom widgets defined by me. These `QRowWidget`s contain `QLineEdit`s and other standard widgets. To show or hide certain parts of a `QRowWidget`, I overdefined the `focusInEvent()` methodes of all the widgets within it. It works perfectly, when I click on the `QRowWidget`, the hidden elements appear.

The weird thing is that the blinking cursor line hovewer doesn't appear in the `QLineEdit`s within the custom widgets. I can select them both by a mouse click or with Tab, and a glow effect indicates that the `QLineEdit` is selected in it, I can select a text in it, or start typing at any location wherever I clicked, but the cursor never appears and it's quite annoying.

My 1st thought was that it is a bug on Mac, but I have the same experience on SuSe Linux.

I'm using python 2.7 and PyQt4.

This is in the `__init__()` of the `QRowWidget`:

```
   for i in self.findChildren(QWidget):
        i.focusInEvent = self.focusInEvent
```

And then this is the own `focusInEvent()`:

```
def focusInEvent(self, event):
    if self.pself.focusedLine:
        self.pself.focusedLine.setStyleSheet("color: #666;")
        self.pself.focusedLine.desc.hide()
        self.pself.focusedLine.closebutton.hide()
    self.setStyleSheet("color: #000;")
    self.desc.show()
    self.closebutton.show()
    self.pself.focusedLine = self
```

Comment: can you post the code of your `focusInEvent()`?  I answered on a hunch, but showing exactly what you are doing will get you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you do not make a call to the original `focusInEvent()` when you override it.  Your function should look something like:

```
 def focusInEvent(self,...):
     QParent.focusInEvent(self,...)
     # the rest of your code
```

where `QParent` is the nearest base class for your widgets is.

Either that, or make sure you call `focusInEvent()` on your `QLineEdit` widgets as part of your function.

Given the comments, it sounds like you are dynamically reassigning the `focusInEvent` function on the insantiatations in your custom widget.  I would either make a derived class for each of the widgets you use that just overrides `focusInEvent` as above, or include a line like

```
type(self).focusInEvent(self,..)
```

in you function.

Comment: What I do is that I iterate through all the children of the custom widget and overwrite all their `focusInEvent()` methods. How can I still call the original methods thereafter?

Comment: The `focusInEvent` you set on them needs to make the call to the original.  I strongly suspect that this is the call that puts the blinking cursor in the `QLineEdit` boxes.

Comment: Okay, but on one hand I need to override the function to do my own stuff, on the other hand I still need to call the original function. How can I do that? (I guess catching the same events like focusInEvent would be one way, but is there a more conveinient one?)

Comment: Got it, the problem was indeed that the original `focusInEvent` was not called. Thanks for the help!

(Funny thing, if I redefine the `focusOutEvent`s the same way without calling the originals, I get cursors blinking everywhere where I clicked once :) )